# Changing layout and preferred size in Swing unicenta opos

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel

How to change layout manager and how to make any component free to resize without any reference in changing other component?

I am work on unicenta 3.7 source code to modify the `JPanel` `Ticket`, but when I change the preferred size from properties, it's kind of something dynamic return the original preferred  size generated code, so:

**my question is how as eg , how to chage layout manager and how to make any component free to resize without any reference in changing other component , i feel like there are a magnetic force between components in the image above, that when you move Jtext field the buttons affected by it**

Here is the image of `Ticket`:

[image]

And here is the source code panel `Ticket.form`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<Form version="1.5" maxVersion="1.9" type="org.netbeans.modules.form.forminfo.JPanelFormInfo">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="background" type="java.awt.Color" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.ColorEditor">
      <Color blue="99" green="cc" red="ff" type="rgb"/>
    </Property>
  </Properties>
  <AuxValues>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_autoResourcing" type="java.lang.Integer" value="0"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_autoSetComponentName" type="java.lang.Boolean" value="false"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_generateFQN" type="java.lang.Boolean" value="true"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_generateMnemonicsCode" type="java.lang.Boolean" value="false"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_i18nAutoMode" type="java.lang.Boolean" value="false"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_layoutCodeTarget" type="java.lang.Integer" value="1"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_listenerGenerationStyle" type="java.lang.Integer" value="0"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_variablesLocal" type="java.lang.Boolean" value="false"/>
    <AuxValue name="FormSettings_variablesModifier" type="java.lang.Integer" value="2"/>
    <AuxValue name="designerSize" type="java.awt.Dimension" value="-84,-19,0,5,115,114,0,18,106,97,118,97,46,97,119,116,46,68,105,109,101,110,115,105,111,110,65,-114,-39,-41,-84,95,68,20,2,0,2,73,0,6,104,101,105,103,104,116,73,0,5,119,105,100,116,104,120,112,0,0,1,-24,0,0,3,17"/>
  </AuxValues>

  <Layout class="org.netbeans.modules.form.compat2.layouts.DesignCardLayout"/>
  <SubComponents>
    <Container class="javax.swing.JPanel" name="m_jPanContainer">
      <Constraints>
        <Constraint layoutClass="org.netbeans.modules.form.compat2.layouts.DesignCardLayout" value="org.netbeans.modules.form.compat2.layouts.DesignCardLayout$CardConstraintsDescription">
          <CardConstraints cardName="ticket"/>
        </Constraint>
      </Constraints>

      <Layout class="org.netbeans.modules.form.compat2.layouts.DesignBorderLayout"/>
      <SubComponents>
        <Container class="javax.swing.JPanel" name="m_jOptions">
          <Constraints>
            <Constraint layoutClass="org.netbeans.modules.form.compat2.layouts.DesignBorderLayout" value="org.netbeans.modules.form.compat2.layouts.DesignBorderLayout$BorderConstraintsDescription">
              <BorderConstraints direction="North"/>
            </Constraint>
          </Constraints>

          <Layout class="org.netbeans.modules.form.compat2.layouts.DesignBorderLayout"/>
          <SubComponents>
            <Container class="javax.swing.JPanel" name="m_jButtons">
              <Constraints>
                <Constraint layoutClass="org.netbeans.modules.form.compat2.layouts.DesignBorderLayout" value="org.netbeans.modules.form.compat2.layouts.DesignBorderLayout$BorderConstraintsDescription">
                  <BorderConstraints direction="Before"/>
                </Constraint>
              </Constraints>

              <Layout>
                <DimensionLayout dim="0">
                  <Group type="103" groupAlignment="0" attributes="0">
                      <Group type="102" alignment="0" attributes="0">
                          <EmptySpace min="5" pref="5" max="-2" attributes="0"/>
                          <Component id="jButton1" min="-2" max="-2" attributes="0"/>
                          <EmptySpace max="32767" attributes="0"/>
                          <Component id="btnCustomer" min="-2" max="-2" attributes="0"/>
                          <EmptySpace max="32767" attributes="0"/>
                          <Component id="btnSplit" min="-2" max="-2" attributes="0"/>
                          <EmptySpace max="32767" attributes="0"/>
                      </Group>
                  </Group>
                </DimensionLayout>
                <DimensionLayout dim="1">
                  <Group type="103" groupAlignment="0" attributes="0">
                      <Group type="102" attributes="0">
                          <EmptySpace min="5" pref="5" max="-2" attributes="0"/>
                          <Group type="103" groupAlignment="0" attributes="0">
                              <Component id="jButton1" min="-2" max="-2" attributes="0"/>
                              <Component id="btnCustomer" min="-2" max="-2" attributes="0"/>
                              <Component id="btnSplit" min="-2" max="-2" attributes="0"/>
                          </Group>
                          <EmptySpace min="-2" pref="5" max="-2" attributes="0"/>
                      </Group>
                  </Group>
                </DimensionLayout>
              </Layout>
              <SubComponents>
                <Component class="javax.swing.JButton" name="jButton1">
                  <Properties>
                    <Property name="icon" type="javax.swing.Icon" editor="org.netbeans.modules.form.editors2.IconEditor">
                      <Image iconType="3" name="/com/openbravo/images/customer_add_sml.png"/>
                    </Property>
                    <Property name="toolTipText" type="java.lang.String" value="Add New Customer"/>
                    <Property name="focusPainted" type="boolean" value="false"/>
                    <Property name="focusable" type="boolean" value="false"/>
                    <Property name="margin" type="java.awt.Insets" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.InsetsEditor">
                      <Insets value="[0, 4, 0, 4]"/>
                    </Property>
                    <Property name="maximumSize" type="java.awt.Dimension" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.DimensionEditor">
                      <Dimension value="[50, 40]"/>
                    </Property>
                    <Property name="minimumSize" type="java.awt.Dimension" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.DimensionEditor">
                      <Dimension value="[50, 40]"/>
                    </Property>
                    <Property name="preferredSize" type="java.awt.Dimension" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.DimensionEditor">
                      <Dimension value="[50, 40]"/>
                    </Property>
                    <Property name="requestFocusEnabled" type="boolean" value="false"/>
                  </Properties>
                  <Events>
                    <EventHandler event="actionPerformed" listener="java.awt.event.ActionListener" parameters="java.awt.event.ActionEvent" handler="jButton1ActionPerformed"/>
                  </Events>
                </Component>
                <Component class="javax.swing.JButton" name="btnCustomer">
                  <Properties>
                    <Property name="icon" type="javax.swing.Icon" editor="org.netbeans.modules.form.editors2.IconEditor">
                      <Image iconType="3" name="/com/openbravo/images/customer_sml.png"/>
                    </Property>
                    <Property name="toolTipText" type="java.lang.String" value="Show Customers"/>
                    <Property name="focusPainted" type="boolean" value="false"/>
                    <Property name="focusable" type="boolean" value="false"/>
                    <Property name="margin" type="java.awt.Insets" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.InsetsEditor">
                      <Insets value="[0, 4, 0, 4]"/>
                    </Property>
                    <Property name="maximumSize" type="java.awt.Dimension" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.DimensionEditor">
                      <Dimension value="[50, 40]"/>
                    </Property>
                    <Property name="minimumSize" type="java.awt.Dimension" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.DimensionEditor">
                      <Dimension value="[50, 40]"/>
                    </Property>
                    <Property name="preferredSize" type="java.awt.Dimension" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.DimensionEditor">
                      <Dimension value="[50, 40]"/>
                    </Property>
                    <Property name="requestFocusEnabled" type="boolean" value="false"/>
                  </Properties>
                  <Events>
                    <EventHandler event="actionPerformed" listener="java.awt.event.ActionListener" parameters="java.awt.event.ActionEvent" handler="btnCustomerActionPerformed"/>
                  </Events>
                </Component>
                <Component class="javax.swing.JButton" name="btnSplit">
                  <Properties>
                    <Property name="icon" type="javax.swing.Icon" editor="org.netbeans.modules.form.editors2.IconEditor">
                      <Image iconType="3" name="/com/openbravo/images/sale_split_sml.png"/>
                    </Property>
                    <Property name="toolTipText" type="java.lang.String" value="Split Sale"/>
                    <Property name="focusPainted" type="boolean" value="false"/>
                    <Property name="focusable" type="boolean" value="false"/>
                    <Property name="margin" type="java.awt.Insets" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.InsetsEditor">
                      <Insets value="[0, 4, 0, 4]"/>
                    </Property>
                    <Property name="maximumSize" type="java.awt.Dimension" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.DimensionEditor">
                      <Dimension value="[50, 40]"/>
                    </Property>
                    <Property name="minimumSize" type="java.awt.Dimension" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.DimensionEditor">
                      <Dimension value="[50, 40]"/>
                    </Property>
                    <Property name="preferredSize" type="java.awt.Dimension" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.DimensionEditor">
                      <Dimension value="[50, 40]"/>
                    </Property>
                    <Property name="requestFocusEnabled" type="boolean" value="false"/>
                  </Properties>
                  <Events>
                    <EventHandler event="actionPerformed" listener="java.awt.event.ActionListener" parameters="java.awt.event.ActionEvent" handler="btnSplitActionPerformed"/>
                  </Events>
                </Component>
              </SubComponents>
            </Container>
            <Container class="javax.swing.JPanel" name="m_jPanelScripts">
              <Constraints>
                <Constraint layoutClass="org.netbeans.modules.form.compat2.layouts.DesignBorderLayout" value="org.netbeans.modules.form.compat2.layouts.DesignBorderLayout$BorderConstraintsDescription">
                  <BorderConstraints direction="After"/>
                </Constraint>
              </Constraints>

              <Layout class="org.netbeans.modules.form.compat2.layouts.DesignBorderLayout"/>
              <SubComponents>
                <Container class="javax.swing.JPanel" name="m_jButtonsExt">
                  <Constraints>
                    <Constraint layoutClass="org.netbeans.modules.form.compat2.layouts.DesignBorderLayout" value="org.netbeans.modules.form.compat2.layouts.DesignBorderLayout$BorderConstraintsDescription">
                      <BorderConstraints direction="After"/>
                    </Constraint>
                  </Constraints>

                  <Layout class="org.netbeans.modules.form.compat2.layouts.DesignBoxLayout"/>
                  <SubComponents>
                    <Container class="javax.swing.JPanel" name="jPanel1">
                      <Properties>
                        <Property name="minimumSize" type="java.awt.Dimension" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.DimensionEditor">
                          <Dimension value="[235, 50]"/>
                        </Property>
                      </Properties>

                      <Layout class="org.netbeans.modules.form.compat2.layouts.DesignFlowLayout"/>
                      <SubComponents>
                        <Component class="javax.swing.JButton" name="m_jbtnScale">
                          <Properties>
                            <Property name="font" type="java.awt.Font" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.FontEditor">
                              <Font name="Arial" size="11" style="0"/>
                            </Property>
                            <Property name="icon" type="javax.swing.Icon" editor="org.netbeans.modules.form.editors2.IconEditor">
                              <Image iconType="3" name="/com/openbravo/images/scale.png"/>
                            </Property>
                            <Property name="text" type="java.lang.String" editor="org.netbeans.modules.i18n.form.FormI18nStringEditor">
                              <ResourceString bundle="pos_messages.properties" key="button.scale" replaceFormat="AppLocal.getIntString(&quot;{key}&quot;)"/>
                            </Property>
                            <Property name="toolTipText" type="java.lang.String" value="Scale"/>
                            <Property name="focusPainted" type="boolean" value="false"/>
                            <Property name="focusable" type="boolean" value="false"/>
                            <Property name="margin" type="java.awt.Insets" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.InsetsEditor">
                              <Insets value="[8, 14, 8, 14]"/>
                            </Property>
                            <Property name="maximumSize" type="java.awt.Dimension" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.DimensionEditor">
                              <Dimension value="[85, 44]"/>
                            </Property>
                            <Property name="minimumSize" type="java.awt.Dimension" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.DimensionEditor">
                              <Dimension value="[85, 44]"/>
                            </Property>
                            <Property name="preferredSize" type="java.awt.Dimension" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.DimensionEditor">
                              <Dimension value="[85, 40]"/>
                            </Property>
                            <Property name="requestFocusEnabled" type="boolean" value="false"/>
                          </Properties>
                          <Events>
                            <EventHandler event="actionPerformed" listener="java.awt.event.ActionListener" parameters="java.awt.event.ActionEvent" handler="m_jbtnScaleActionPerformed"/>
                          </Events>
                        </Component>
                        <Component class="javax.swing.JButton" name="jbtnMooring">
                          <Properties>
                            <Property name="font" type="java.awt.Font" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.FontEditor">
                              <Font name="Arial" size="11" style="0"/>
                            </Property>
                            <Property name="text" type="java.lang.String" editor="org.netbeans.modules.i18n.form.FormI18nStringEditor">
                              <ResourceString bundle="pos_messages.properties" key="button.moorings" replaceFormat="java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(&quot;{bundleNameSlashes}&quot;).getString(&quot;{key}&quot;)"/>
                            </Property>
                            <Property name="margin" type="java.awt.Insets" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.InsetsEditor">
                              <Insets value="[8, 14, 8, 14]"/>
                            </Property>
                            <Property name="maximumSize" type="java.awt.Dimension" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.DimensionEditor">
                              <Dimension value="[80, 40]"/>
                            </Property>
                            <Property name="minimumSize" type="java.awt.Dimension" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.DimensionEditor">
                              <Dimension value="[80, 40]"/>
                            </Property>
                            <Property name="preferredSize" type="java.awt.Dimension" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.DimensionEditor">
                              <Dimension value="[80, 40]"/>
                            </Property>
                          </Properties>
                          <Events>
                            <EventHandler event="actionPerformed" listener="java.awt.event.ActionListener" parameters="java.awt.event.ActionEvent" handler="jbtnMooringActionPerformed"/>
                          </Events>
                        </Component>
                        <Component class="javax.swing.JButton" name="j_btnKitchenPrt">
                          <Properties>
                            <Property name="icon" type="javax.swing.Icon" editor="org.netbeans.modules.form.editors2.IconEditor">
                              <Image iconType="3" name="/com/openbravo/images/printer24.png"/>
                            </Property>
                            <Property name="text" type="java.lang.String" editor="org.netbeans.modules.i18n.form.FormI18nStringEditor">
                              <ResourceString bundle="pos_messages.properties" key="button.sendorder" replaceFormat="java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(&quot;{bundleNameSlashes}&quot;).getString(&quot;{key}&quot;)"/>
                            </Property>
                            <Property name="toolTipText" type="java.lang.String" value="Send to Kichen Printer"/>
                            <Property name="margin" type="java.awt.Insets" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.InsetsEditor">
                              <Insets value="[0, 4, 0, 4]"/>
                            </Property>
                            <Property name="maximumSize" type="java.awt.Dimension" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.DimensionEditor">
                              <Dimension value="[50, 40]"/>
                            </Property>
                            <Property name="minimumSize" type="java.awt.Dimension" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.DimensionEditor">
                              <Dimension value="[50, 40]"/>
                            </Property>
                            <Property name="preferredSize" type="java.awt.Dimension" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.DimensionEditor">
                              <Dimension value="[50, 40]"/>
                            </Property>
                          </Properties>
                          <Events>
                            <EventHandler event="actionPerformed" listener="java.awt.event.ActionListener" parameters="java.awt.event.ActionEvent" handler="j_btnKitchenPrtActionPerformed"/>
                          </Events>
                        </Component>
                      </SubComponents>
                    </Container>
                  </SubComponents>
                </Container>
              </SubComponents>
            </Container>
            <Container class="javax.swing.JPanel" name="m_jPanelBag">
              <Properties>
                <Property name="preferredSize" type="java.awt.Dimension" editor="org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.DimensionEditor">
                  <Dimension value="[0, 50]"/>
                </Property>
              </Properties>
              <Constraints>
                <Constraint layoutClass="org.netbeans.modules.form.compat2.layouts.DesignBorderLayout" value="org.netbeans.modules.form.compat2.layouts.DesignBorderLayout$BorderConstraintsDescription">
                  <BorderConstraints direction="Center"/>
                </Constraint>
              </Constraints>

              <Layout class="org.netbeans.modules.form.compat2.layouts.DesignBorderLayout"/>
            </Container>
          </SubComponents>
        </Container>
        <Container class="javax.swing.JPanel" name="m_jPanTicket">
          <Properties>
            <Property name="border" type="javax.swing.border.Border" editor="org.netbeans.modules.form.editors2.BorderEditor">
              <Border info="org.netbeans.modules.form.compat2.border.EmptyBorderInfo">
                <EmptyBorder bottom="5" left="5" right="5" top="5"/>
              </Border>
            </Property>
          </Properties>
          <Constraints>
            <Constraint layoutClass="org.netbeans.modules.form.compat2.layouts.DesignBorderLayout" value="org.netbeans.modules.form.compat2.layouts.DesignBorderLayout$BorderConstraintsDescription">
              <BorderConstraints direction="Center"/>
            </Constraint>
          </Constraints>
```

Comment: 1) See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.) 2) What is your actual question?

Comment: my question is how as eg , how to chage layout manager and how to make any component free to resize without any reference in changing other component , i feel like there are a magnetic force between components in the image above, that when you move Jtext field the buttons affected by it

Comment: That should be part of the main question (I did it for you this time).

Answer (score -1):

you will find a gap between the controls just double click it and make it resizable to be able to move the controls without resize the other controls but instead the gaps will resize